# How can i implement an ASP.NT MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I am new to .NET FRAMEWORK, and am trying to come up with an ASP.NET MVC API for a real estate.
In my database, I have a table Product and Amenity. My assumption is a Product e.g Apartment can have several Amenities e.g [{ 'Gym' }, { 'Wifi' }]. Therefore, I have created another table ProductAmenity that references Product and Amenity.

I have so far come up with Product Class, Amenity class and ProductAmenity class with the corresponding ProductsController and ProductAmenitiesController. Currently when I do a get request on my ProductsController, it returns all the other values except it returns a NULL value in the Object- ProductAmenity despite their being data in the table ProductAmenity.

```js
Here are my controllers:

namespace api_realEstate.Controllers
{
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        readonly RealEstateDBEntities entities;
        public ProductsController()
        {
            entities = new RealEstateDBEntities();
        }
        private List<ProductView> PrepProducts(List<Product> dbProducts)
        {
            var productsView = new List<ProductView>();
            foreach (var product in dbProducts)
            {
                productsView.Add(
                    new ProductView
                    {
                        Id = product.ID,
                        Category = product.Category,
                        Address = product.Location,
                        Amount = product.Price,
                        Beds = product.Bathroom,
                        Baths = product.Bedroom,
                        Area = product.Area,
                        Parking = product.Parking,
                        ParkingSpot = product.ParkingSpot,
                        Description = product.Description,
                        Term = product.Term,
                        UserId = product.UserID
                    });
            }
            return productsView;
        }
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var dbProducts = entities.Products.ToList();
            return Ok(PrepProducts(dbProducts));
        }
 } 
} 

namespace api_realEstate.Controllers
{
    public class AmenitiesController : ApiController
    {
        readonly RealEstateDBEntities entities;
        public AmenitiesController()
        {
            entities = new RealEstateDBEntities();
        }
        private List<AmenityView> PrepAmenities(List<Amenity> dbAmenities)
        {
            var amenitiesView = new List<AmenityView>();
            foreach (var amenity in dbAmenities)
            {
                amenitiesView.Add(
                    new AmenityView
                    {
                        Id = amenity.ID,
                        Itemname = amenity.ItemName                       
                    });
            }
            return amenitiesView;
        }
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var dbAmenities = entities.Amenities.ToList();
            return Ok(PrepAmenities(dbAmenities));
        }
 }
} 

namespace api_realEstate.Controllers
{
    public class ProductAmenitiesController : ApiController
    {
        readonly RealEstateDBEntities entities;
        public ProductAmenitiesController()
        {
            entities = new RealEstateDBEntities();
        }
        private List<ProductAmenityView> PrepProductAmenities(List<ProductAmenity> dbProdAmenity)
        {
            var prodamenityView = new List<ProductAmenityView>();
            foreach (var prodamenity in dbProdAmenity)
            {
                prodamenityView.Add(
                    new ProductAmenityView
                    {
                        Id = prodamenity.ID,
                        Productid = prodamenity.ProductID,
                        Amenityid = prodamenity.AmenityID                        
                    });
            }
            return prodamenityView;
        }
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var dbProdAmenity = entities.ProductAmenities.ToList();
            return Ok(PrepProductAmenities(dbProdAmenity));
        }
 }
}
```

```html
Here are my classes:

public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.ProductAmenities = new HashSet<ProductAmenity>();
            this.ProductImages = new HashSet<ProductImage>();
        }    
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Bedroom { get; set; }
        public int Bathroom { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Area { get; set; }
        public string Parking { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParkingSpot { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Term { get; set; }
        public long UserID { get; set; }    
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductAmenity> ProductAmenities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages { get; set; }
    } 
    
public partial class Amenity
    {      
        public Amenity()
        {
            this.ProductAmenities = new HashSet<ProductAmenity>();
        }    
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductAmenity> ProductAmenities { get; set; }
    }
    
public partial class ProductAmenity
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long ProductID { get; set; }
        public long AmenityID { get; set; }    
        public virtual Amenity Amenity { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```

I expect that when I do a (GET) request to my ProductsController, I should have values returned in my ProductAmenity object.
How can I apply the relationship between these tables: Product, Amenity and ProductAmenity within my Controller?

Comment: somewhere you are missing the mapping, you are creating DBview to combine both the things and getting it right?

Comment: What do you mean by _Relationship_? Are you maybe talking about creating ViewModels for transferring selected properties of your models to the client?

Comment: @schlonzo Correct he is missing the viewmodels, you can create view model, like below answer suggested.

Comment: Your product and Ameneties entities are direct objects which is directly available in DB so you can raise get, But when you create relationship and merging them together you can create a DBVIEW in Database and you can merge the object in code using viewmodels and can map with the DB view and fetch it accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Following your suggestions, I created a  DbView and merged my object-ProductAmenity, with the view and it works fine.

Comment: Glad it helped, Enjoy coding. Please go through about View models, Repository Patterns, Unit of work and make sure in Solid Principles which will help you long go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need Include like this:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
 {
      var dbProducts = entities.Products.Include(x => x.ProductAmenities).ToList();
      return Ok(PrepProducts(dbProducts));
 }
```

And then in PrepProducts Action instead of foreach use this one:

```
  var productsView = dbProducts.Select(product => new ProductView {
                            Id = product.ID,
                            Category = product.Category,
                            Address = product.Location,
                            Amount = product.Price,
                            Beds = product.Bathroom,
                            Baths = product.Bedroom,
                            Area = product.Area,
                            Parking = product.Parking,
                            ParkingSpot = product.ParkingSpot,
                            Description = product.Description,
                            Term = product.Term,
                            UserId = product.UserID,
                            ProductAmenities = product.ProductAmenities.Select(//use viewmodel to cast it, like to ProductView )

                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
In the productsView Model I just added this and it worked:

private List<ProductView> PrepProducts(List<Product> dbProducts)
        {
            var productsView = new List<ProductView>();
            foreach (var product in dbProducts)
            {
                productsView.Add(
                    new ProductView
                    {
                        Id = product.ID,
                        UserId = product.UserID,
                        Category = product.Category,
                        Address = product.Location,
                        Amount = product.Price,
                        Beds = product.Bathroom,
                        Baths = product.Bedroom,
                        Area = product.Area,
                        Parking = product.Parking,
                        ParkingSpot = product.ParkingSpot,
                        Description = product.Description,
                        Term = product.Term,

                        Amenities = product.ProductAmenities.Select(x => new Models.ProductAmenity
                        {
                            Id = x.ID,
                            Amenity = new AmenityView
                            {
                                Id = x.Amenity.ID,
                                Itemname = x.Amenity.ItemName
                            }
                        }).ToList()
                      
            });
            return productsView;
        }
```